# When injecting an HTML template with a Google Chrome extension with various scripts, jQuery doesn't seem to import

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

To elaborate, I am injecting and loading an HTML template in my Google Chrome extension like this:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
            
            var PBSKPage = xhttp.responseText;
            document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = "";
            loadPBSKPage();
            function loadPBSKPage() {
                
                document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = PBSKPage;
            }
        }
    };
function insertAndExecute() {
    var scripts = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("script"));
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        if (scripts[i].src != "") {
            var tag = document.createElement("script");
            tag.src = scripts[i].src;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
        }
        else {
            eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my HTML template, I clearly put the script tag that requests jQuery before the jQuery-reliant scripts:

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="chrome-extension://niabfndainielhgpcjenbpodannhfofj/2015/pbsk_resources/wildkratts/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="chrome-extension://niabfndainielhgpcjenbpodannhfofj/2015/pbsk_resources/wildkratts/js/vendor/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="chrome-extension://niabfndainielhgpcjenbpodannhfofj/2015/pbsk_resources/wildkratts/js/vendor/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="chrome-extension://niabfndainielhgpcjenbpodannhfofj/2015/pbsk_resources/wildkratts/js/vendor/retina.min.js"></script>
...
```

jQuery doesn't seem to import, and when the JS files are executed, the browser always spits out an Uncaught TypeError on something that would be defined if jQuery was imported.

So what do I do? Is this because of CSP? Is it because of the insertAndExecute() function? Is it because of the intrinsic inner workings of Google Chrome extensions? I suppose I could just paste the jQuery JS into each of the jQuery-reliant JS files, but that wouldn't be very efficient. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a high enough rep to comment on the answer above mine, but bundling jQuery with your code and the libraries you wish to use should do the trick. That said, it might be a good idea to use a more up-to-date version of jQuery since it's received a number of significant security patches since version 1.11.

Comment: So the only solution is to just paste jQuery inside the JS files that need it?

Comment: Odd, whenever I go to the HTML template itself, it executes the scripts just fine with no errors, however whenever I go to the live page which is overriden by the HTML template (pbskids.org/wildkratts/), it has trouble executing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is an issue with the CSP as chrome does not want people to link external libraries and change them later maliciously or not. You can get the jQuery library and add it to your project explicitly but yes it is more work :(

Comment: I think it's also possible to change the CSP such that it works as you have it, but I don't remember how to do that

Comment: So basically, I just have to copy the entire jQuery library code and just paste it into the JS files that need it?

Comment: @ThePiGuy yeah you can do that or preferably, do it as a separate file and link it in the html with `<script src="LOCATION/NAME.js"></script>`, where LOCATION/NAME is the relative location of the jQuery library

Comment: So just put this; `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and insert it into the HTML? Also what do you mean by "relative location of the jQuery library"?

Comment: Download jQuery here: https://jquery.com/download/ and move it into your project. Then put the location as where you put the jQuery js file relative to the html file

Comment: Li So like this? `<script src="chrome-extension://niabfndainielhgpcjenbpodannhfofj/jquery_libraries/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` And then insert it into the HTML template that way? The errors still appear as if jQuery has still not been imported at all.

Comment: no like `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` if jQuery.js is in the save level as your popup.html

Comment: Li Well since I'm replacing entire pages with my HTML template, just pasting the filename into the src attribute requests it from the root of the URL. Oh well, I'll guess I'll have to resort to pasting jQuery's code into each of the JS files.